# Winforms: Programmatically Resize Form to Fit Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which contains 4 Panel controls and each panel control in turn, has their own child controls.

Inside one of the panel controls (call it panel1), I have a datagridview control and I'm resizing this control to fit the number of rows returned by the query.  I have also set the autosize property of panel1 to true and GrowAndShrink.

I use the following code to calculate the new height of the form after updating panel1 height in the DataBindingComplete event handler for the datagridview control:

```
Height = Controls.OfType<Panel>().Cast<Control>().Where(c => c.Visible).Sum(c => c.Height + c.Margin.Vertical);
```

However, the form never resizes to fit all inner panels, causing some overlap of the panels.

I still want to give the user the ability to resize the form after updating it's height which is why I didn't opt to set the autosize property of the form to true.

Comment: I've made a custom  function to resize the user controls when the form is resized. It works for me, as per my requirement, would you like me to post it as answer

Comment: My issue is the opposite of what you described.  I would like to resize the form to fit the controls when one of the controls is resized.

Comment: Yea i got the point and I'm working on it. If i could come up with a solution will post the same

Comment: That would be great!!!  Thank you!

Comment: You're setting the height of the form but I believe you're not taking into account the height of the title bar.  Try setting the `ClientHeight` property instead of `Height`

Comment: I just tried using ClientSize and still having same problem.  I even put code to adjust height in the SizeChanged event handlers for the 4 panels just to ensure I'm using the updated panel size in my calculations.

Comment: Also, when I set the ClientHeight the form becomes a little too big leaving a bit of space between a couple of the panels.